# Deleting rows using not exists taking over 1 hour to finish

Tags: sql, plsql

Table has a million records. I'm deleting the records using not exists.It is taking more than 1 hour.

My sample code:

```
delete from emp emp
       where empno=l_empno  --l_empno is parameter passing from procedure
       and not exists(select 1
                      from employees emps
                      where   emps.ename=  emp.ename);
```

Comment: _"l_empno is parameter passing from procedure"_ So, you're calling this procedure for each ... record in emp? I very much doubt that the delete statement itself is taking 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks Mackan for reply. Yes, Delete statement is taking time. Any other solution please

Comment: That doesn't even come close to answering my question. Of course it will take time calling this procedure 'millions' of times. Put indexes on the ename columns and it might be faster (and also _alot_ bigger). If you want better solutions and feedback post more details.

Comment: In the above l_empno say value 123.If i use direct value also it is taking more time.

Comment: Try running the select statement instead of the delete statement and see how long it takes. Also, check out the actual execution plan to see if there is anything that can improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try switching off logging and delete the rows,

```
alter table table_name nologging ;
```

both testemp and testemp2 are same tables with same data 
while testemp takes over a minute , testemp2 takes only 1 second

```
SQL> delete from testemp;

14336 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:01:04.12
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> alter table testemp2 nologging;

Table altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.86
SQL>
SQL> delete from testemp2;

14336 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.26
SQL>
```

EDIT :

The table needs to be put back to logging  only when we physically change the table using  "Alter" command, if you are using as hint not required please see the example below

```
SQL> set timing on;
SQL> delete  from testemp2;

14336 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.51

Deleting data after reinserting same data into table now with nologging;



SQL> delete /*+NOLOGGING*/ from testemp2;

14336 rows deleted.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.28

SQL> select logging from user_Tables where table_name='TESTEMP2';

LOG
---
YES
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Sheridan , the question was relating to slow delete operations, hence i suggested the nologging method, i have updated my answer to show that nologging the table to show the results

Comment: The point is that your answer was a *suggestion* and not an answer... now it's an answer.

Comment: I have used nologging in the delete statement as hint. Example delete /*+ NOLOGGING */ ..statement follows. My question is If we can  embedded this hint in production database, any effect?.  I have read that nologging will not create redo generation. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Rajus , yes ; what you can do is once the delete operation compeltes, you can again enable logging on the table.

Comment: Hi Anudeepks, I have used as hint in the sql statement.So how to enable it. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much anudeepks for quick help.

Comment: Please, mark the answer as helpful or answered if it has helped you :)

Comment: click on the grey tick mark, next to answer, it will turn green :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many psosibilities:

First if you have no indexes on emp.empn, emps.ename, emp.ename you could be doing a table scan. Check your execution plan. Joining on things like emane is usually a bad idea - it is slower to join on character based datatypes than numeric ones. You have an employee number it appears, can you join on that? Can you redesign your database so that is the field these tables relate on?

Next if you have cascading deletes, you could be deleting many millions of associated records even if you were delting only 1 record in the parent table.

You could have blocking.

You could be trying to delete so many records at once that it is simply taking too long to log the deletes in the transaction log and it needs to grow which slows things down.

You could have a trigger that is slowing things down (Do not remove the trigger if so. That trigger is there for a business reason. You may need to rewrite it to be more set-based.)

And on and on.

First check your execution plan and see if you are missing indexes or what other problems you might see.
Next check to see if you have triggers or cascade deltes. 
Even if you are doing a cascade delete, you might consider if you want to delete child records first  in batches. This is one reason why many dbas do not allow cascade deletes, the uncontrolled deletion of many records.